# Air Android - Recommended framerate?

Tags: android, performance, air

I'm building a note taking app with Adobe Air 3.6 that is only vector based and uses a slider to scroll long list.

What framerate is recommended for an Air Android app?

Comment: The default setting of 24fps should be fine for your app

Comment: Basically, the higher the better. You'll need to hit at least 30 if you want your app to be perceived as fast. With 60fps being the 'smooth as butter' category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no recommended framerate. You can go as high as 60 with 24 being the default. 30 is generally preferred by devs for non-games.

Basically, it is completely dependent on your app. An app at 24fps renders a new frame every 41ms. At 30fps, that is one every 33ms. And at 60, that is one every 16ms. So as your framerate goes up, the time you have to calculate each frame goes down. Depending on what is occurring during that frame calculation, you could have dropped frames (if it takes longer than 1000/fps to render). This will result in a "laggy" display and is generally less favorable than just using a lower framerate (in most cases, the human eye perceives 24fps as smooth).

Additionally, the higher the framerate, the more CPU you use as you are rendering and calculating things far more often. This will have an adverse effect on both the framerate and the battery consumption of your app.

In the end, you need to finish your app and play around with the framerate in a production environment (i.e. doing an "Export Release Build" instead of a debug build) and determine what framerate works best. There is a sweetspot for all apps, but there is no global sweetspot.

Keep in mind as well that there is a wide variety of Android devices out there. While 16ms per frame may be fine on a current-gen flagship (Galaxy S4, Nexus 4, HTC One for phones), it may not be enough time per frame on a lower-end or last-gen model with a slower CPU/GPU

Comment: @Jay It's worth noting that it is uncommon but possible to change your framerate on the fly. 24fps is generally too slow for dragging items on the screen. In the past, I have upped it to 48fps on MOUSE_DOWN and back down to 24 or 30 on MOUSE_UP.

Comment: @ Josh Janusch That's a fantastic idea, thank you!